# how to get to struct vm_area_struct from struct page

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Basically, I need to identify the process or task using a page, and accordingly make some decisions regarding whether to allow the page to be swapped out or not. Because the swap module in kernel AFAIK deals with mostly *struct page*, I was wondering whether there is some existing trick that I am missing. From include/linux/mm_types.h (v >= 2.6), the following comment:

- Each physical page in the system has a struct page associated with
- it to keep track of whatever it is we are using the page for at the
- moment. Note that we have no way to track which tasks are using
- a page, though if it is a pagecache page, rmap structures can tell us
- who is mapping it.

suggests we can do this via some physical-to-virtual reverse mappings, but I could not figure out from the rmap functions (in mm/rmap.c) how to achieve what I am looking for.

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question "how to get to struct vm_area_struct from struct page", there are at least two answers.

For anonymous pages you can use `page_anon_vma()`, which returns an `anon_vma` - it's stored in `page->mapping` with a special flag set to indicate it's not a `struct address_space` (to save space).

From the `anon_vma` you can walk the `anon_vma_chain` and each entry points to a `vma`. From the `vma` you can get the `mm` and then **a** task.

See `page_referenced_anon()` for an example.

For a file page you look at `page->mapping` which is a `struct address_space`, and from there you walk the `i_mmap` which is a `struct prio_tree_root`. See `page_referenced_file()`.

I'm not sure that's actually going to help you implement your idea, but there you go.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is probably what you want.

This is the prototype:

```
// [ http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/rmap.h#L27 ]
149 struct anon_vma *page_get_anon_vma(struct page *page);
```

This is how you might use it:
    // [ http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/ksm.c#L1898 ]
    // [...]

```
        anon_vma = page_get_anon_vma(page);
1902    anon_vma_lock_read(anon_vma);
1903    anon_vma_interval_tree_foreach(vmac, &anon_vma->rb_root,
1904                                                0, ULONG_MAX) {
1906                         vma = vmac->vma;
1907                         if (page_address < vma->vm_start ||
1908                             page_address >= vma->vm_end)
1909                                 continue;
[...]   }
        anon_vma_unlock_read(anon_vma);
```